# MongoDB aggregation - grouping results by containing text

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have objects of the following type:

```
"name":string,
"title": string,
"body": string
```

I need to perform aggregation query which looks for objects that contain specific text in one of fields. The results should be grouped by the following rules:

1. First objects that their name contains text.
2. Then objects that their title contains text.
3. Then objects that their body contains text.

The first stage of the aggregation looks like this:

```
"$match" : {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "name" : /.*hellow world.*/i
                    }, 
                    {
                        "title" : /.*hellow world.*/i
                    }, 
                    {
                        "body" : /.*hellow world.*/i
                    }
                ]
            }
```

- **Also, I'm using paging.**
- **The query being requested from node.js server.**

My first problem is I still did not figure out whether it is possible at all to perform such a grouping in aggregation pipeline.

Also, I'm trying to perform three queries first to get results that their name contains term, then those that their title and then body. Using this method I have few other problems: three queries to a server not so efficient and also managing paging adds complexity to whole process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) to apply your criteria separately and then run [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) to merge the results:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $facet: {
            name: [ { $match: { "name" : /.*hello world.*/i } } ],
            title: [ { $match: { "title" : /.*hello world.*/i } } ],
            body: [ { $match: { "body" : /.*hello world.*/i } } ],
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            data: {
                $concatArrays: [ "$name", "$title", "$body" ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Hah!. I was thinking in terms of grouping or sorting. Thank you man.